# iPhone sdk 3.2.3 upgrade Problem

Tags: iphone

I just upgraded my Mac to Snow Leopard, and installed Xcode 3.2.3.

The app I am working on ran perfectly before the upgrade.

Now, the default image appears briefly, then the screen goes black except for the status bar. Same behavior on my iPhone 4 and in the simulator, whether I target iOS 3.2 or 4.

The app is still running and I an see from traces and in the debugger that the app is running normally, and my root view controller has been loaded, but nothing but blackness on screen

Anyone seen this before?

Thanks

JK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I needed to add [window makeKeyAndVisible]; to my applicationDidLaunch method. Wonder why it worked before, with just the wired up XIB file???

Comment: no idea. The newer SDKs have become stricter on IB implementation stuff it seems, so perhaps that has something to do with it.